# Running .bat file in java to create a .csv file

Tags: java, batch-file

I am trying to execute a bat file using java. This bat file contains code that should create a .csv file in the same directory. The .csv file is successfully created when I execute the .bat file by running it on my Windows machine, however when I try to execute it in java using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, the file does not get created.

```
String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "C:/Users/MidiCsv/ex.bat"};
Process p = null;
try {
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("ready");
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
content = Files.readString(Paths.get("C:/Users/MidiCsv/" + midiName + ".csv"), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

The value returned by the p.waitFor() method is 2, I assume this means there was an error here since the normal return value is 0. What error could this indicate?

Comment: Q: Does ex.bat need to read a file from the current directory?  Which might be *different* if you're invoking the .bat file from Java?

Comment: Hi paulsm4, I edited my original post to add the info regarding the return value of waitFor(). And to answer your question, yes the .bat file runs a .exe file in the current directory.

Comment: "waitFor() = 2" can mean anything at all - or nothing whatsoever.  HOWEVER: I'm guessing that it probably *DOES* mean something here: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`.  STRONG SUGGESTION:  Modify your .bat file to `cd C:\Users\MidiCsv` and see of that changes the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the working directory is required to be same as your batch file, use this variant of exec method instead:

```
public Process exec(String[] cmdarray,
           String[] envp,
           File dir)
             throws IOException
```

Reference: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File))

Make dir the directory containing your batch file.

Comment: Hi Febtober, I tried using this method. `p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c ex.bat", null, new File(batPath));` This is giving me an error that the directory name is invalid. I suspect that the previous problem was that exec() could not find the batch file. I got batPath through `String batPath = new File("src/sample/Resources/Midi/MidiCsv/ex.bat").getAbsolutePath();`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the error from taking the helpful advice here. I used the exec() variant Febtober mentioned, also previously I was putting the absolute path of the .batch file as the dir paramter, whereas I should have put the directory of the .batch file instead.